ELMo embedding not working - causing 0 params in the model summary
I am attempting to create a text classification CNN model with ELMo embedding however the model summary is showing 0 params. It seems the ELMo embedding is not applying properly but not sure on the issue.
#setting up parameters
max_length = 200
no_of_filters = 250
kernel_size = 3
hidden_dims = 250
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor ='val_loss', patience = 10)

#obtaining elmo emmbedding
elmo = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", 
                  trainable=True,
                  name = 'elmo_embedding',
                  #input_shape=[],
                 dtype=(tf.string))
model = Sequential()

model.add(Lambda(lambda x: elmo(x), input_shape = [], dtype = tf.string))

model.add(Conv1D(no_of_filters, kernel_size, activation ='relu', input_shape = 
(max_length, 1024)))

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(hidden_dims, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.summary()

The model is then outputting a model summary that shows the model isn't working. I've tried a few different itterations of the code but seems to be the same outcome. Would the embedding need to be applied to the data before being fed through the model or is it possible to do so within the model itself?

I've made some changes to your code. To keep the pretrained ELMo model fixed,
I've set its trainable parameter to False. I've also used tf.keras to add
layers to the Sequential model and reshaped the ELMo output to a 3D format,
which is compatible with Conv1D layers. These changes have made the code
operational. For a detailed look at the updated code, please refer to the
gist.
